# CSS hover animation does not play after link is clicked

Tags: css, animation

I am by no means a CSS expert (hence coming for help here), and I am using a CSS hover animation effect from [this open source effects collection](http://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/).

The particular animation I'm using is "Ripple Out".  I have all my links set up with `target=_"blank"`, and the problem is that after a user clicks one of the links, a new tab opens, but when they come back to the original tab, the hover animation does not play for the link they just clicked on.  I tried playing around with `:visited` but that did not really help.

Here is all the relevant CSS:

```
/* my button styling */

.my-button {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 8px 15px 8px 15px;
  background: #0072C6;
  border: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: large;
  color: white;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 180px;
  text-shadow: 1px 3px 2px #424A8A;
}
a.my-button {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a.my-button:visited {
  color: white;
}

/* the animation CSS */

/* Ripple Out */
@-webkit-keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes hvr-ripple-out {
  100% {
    top: -12px;
    right: -12px;
    bottom: -12px;
    left: -12px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.hvr-ripple-out {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
}
.hvr-ripple-out:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: #0072C6 solid 6px;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: .7s;
  animation-duration: .7s;
}
.hvr-ripple-out:hover:before, .hvr-ripple-out:focus:before, .hvr-ripple-out:active:before {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
  animation-name: hvr-ripple-out;
}
```

The only thing I changed from what is available on github was the background color.

Can anyone figure out how to get the animation to continue playing after returning to the original tab/window, and **explain what is happening with the CSS** so I can learn how it works?

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kd8w1x5/) with everything in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply delete this line and everything should work. What's happening is after you click on the button and return to the page, the button is still `:focus`ed, so the style doesn't clear.

```
.hvr-ripple-out:focus:before,
```